# Is Zephaniah 1:2-3 hyperbolically referring to the coming destruction of Judah?

Tags: hebrew, judgement, zephaniah

Zephaniah 1:2-3 states:

> 2 “I will utterly sweep away everything
> from the face of the earth,” declares the Lord. 3 “I will sweep away man and beast;
> I will sweep away the birds of the heavens
> and the fish of the sea, and the rubble with the wicked.
> I will cut off mankind
> from the face of the earth,” declares the Lord.

I have seen references to this as evidence for the use of hyperbole in the OT. More specifically, I am reading The Lost World of the Flood, and the authors make the case that this passage is evidence in support of their assertion that The Flood account in Genesis, despite its clearly universal language, would have been understood as hyperbolic by the author and their audience. Their assertion seems to be that this passage in Zephaniah uses universal language directed exclusively at the coming destruction of Jerusalem, rather than an universal opening that is eschatological in nature, and subsequently followed by specific prophecy focused on Jerusalem.

> We contend that employing universalistic rhetoric to portray the
> impact and significance of the flood as a cosmic cataclysm does not
> mean that the ancient Israelites or the author considered the physical
> scope or geographical range to be universal. Other uses of
> universalistic language used rhetorically as hyperbole can be
> identified in Lamentations 2:22 (where the lament over the Babylonian
> destruction of Jerusalem indicates that there were no survivors, when
> we are well aware from the rest of the Old Testament that some were
> taken into exile and others remained in the land) and a similar
> discussion of the day of the Lord coming on Jerusalem in Zephaniah 1,
> which indicates that the destruction would be complete and universal.
>
> Longman III, Tremper; Walton, John H.. The Lost World of the Flood: 5
> (The Lost World Series) (p. 36). InterVarsity Press. Kindle Edition

Commentaries seem to vary widely on whether this opening is referring hyperbolically to the coming destruction of Jerusalem, or prophetically to separate, future universal judgement before the rest of the chapter focuses in on Jerusalem.

Comment: Zephaniah is describing here the reversal of the act of creation of Genesis 1. God's judgement as His withdrawal and allowing the collapse of the creation back to its chaotic state of Genesis 1: 2. Just like during the deluge or the plagues in Egypt. He uses the language of previous stories to describe the future destruction of Judah and the surrounding nations by the Babylonians.

Comment: Very similar text: "Hear the word of the LORD, you Israelites! For the LORD has a covenant lawsuit against the people of Israel. For there is neither faithfulness nor loyalty in the land, nor do they acknowledge God. There is only cursing, lying, murder, stealing, and adultery. They resort to violence and bloodshed. Therefore the land will mourn, and all its inhabitants will perish. The wild animals, the birds of the sky, and even the fish in the sea will perish." (Hos. 4:1-3 NET)

Comment: @ארקדיוס Like Dottard below, you have sort of touched on the reason for my question. In The Lost World of the Flood, the authors reference this passage as an example of the use of hyperbole as evidence that the language used in the deluge account was intended to be, and would be understood by ANE contemporaries as hyperbolic. Do you think the language here is supportive of that assertion? That hyperbole is being used to exclusively describe the coming destruction of Judah?

Comment: It is a hyperbole. In similar fashion, The Book of Joshua describes the conquest of Canaan. The Israelites came like a flood and wiped everyone out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP's question appears to imply an answer giving either a fulfilment about the destruction of Jerusalem and Judah or an eschatological fulfillment.  It can be both - see appendix below.

It is obvious and explicit that the bulk of the prophecy of Zeph 1 is directed at Judah and Jerusalem as stated in V4.  However, this does not prevent such events being used as models and language for still future events (again, see appendix below).

**"Day of the LORD"**

"The Day of the LORD" (Zeph 1:7, 14, 18) is a frequent phrase in the Bible and is used to denote a time when great final judgements of God are delivered on people; see for example: Isa 13:9, Jer 25:33, 46:10, Eze 13:5, 30:3, Joel 2:1, 3:14, Amos 5:18, Acts 2:20, 1 Cor 5:5, 1 Thess 5:2, 2 Peter 3:10, 2 Peter 3:12, etc.  This refers to any of the destruction of Jerusalem, the first coming of Jesus and His crucifixion, the second coming of Jesus and the final judgement.

Thus, in Zeph 1 we could have any or all of these events.  However, we can narrow the choice somewhat.  Let us examine Zeph 1:2, 3 and note the events described:

- sweep away everything from the face of the earth
- sweep away man and beast
- sweep away birds of the air and fish of the sea

These events are parallel to and the reverse of the events of creation week as described in Gen 1.  Thus, we have a series of events that is global in nature and extent.  Thus, it appears that Zeph 1 describes events/divine judgements that are directed specifically at Judah and Jerusalem (V4) and global events (V2, 3, 17, 18).

That is, Zeph 1 describes a dual prophecy about the destruction of Judah and Jerusalem as well as the final destruction of all wicked in the great final divine judgements upon the wicked of all the earth.

**APPENDIX - Dual Fulfillment Prophecies**

There are a number of prophecies in Scripture that clearly have a dual fulfillment such as:

1. Matt 24:3 - While Jesus was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to Him privately. “Tell us,” they said, “when will (a) these things happen, and (b) what will be the sign of Your coming and of the end of the age?” Thus, Jesus combined the destruction of Jerusalem with the end of the world when He would return.  This includes the “abomination of desolation”.
2. Isa 7:14 - Therefore the Lord Himself will give you a sign: Behold, the virgin will be with child and will give birth to a son, and will call Him Immanuel. This was a prophecy about Isaiah's wife but was also applied to Mary and Jesus as per Matt 1:23.
3. Joel 2:28-32 is an example of a prophecy that was fulfilled at Pentecost in Acts 2 but which appears to be capable of eschatological fulfillment again in the period before Jesus returns
4. Hos 10:8 is about the wicked asking to be destroyed by rocks and mountains is a prophecy about the destruction of Jerusalem; but it also receives a dual application by Rev 6:15-17 at the end of time when Jesus returns.
5. The prophecy about Gog and Magog in Eze 38 concerns the punishment meted out to these pagan nations in OT times. However, it is given a second impetus in Rev 20:8 in the time after the 1000 years.
6. Mal 4:5 predicts the arrival of Elijah the prophet before the “Day of the Lord” and the NT claims fulfilment in places like Matt 11:13, 14, 17:11-14, Mark 9:12, 13, Luke 1:17 as John the Baptist.  However, the “great and terrible day of the Lord” (Mal 4:5) clearly also has eschatological fulfilment and confirmed by the indirect allusions to Elijah in the book of Revelation.
7. Ps 22 is about the loneliness and isolation of David as were many of his psalms.  However, it has been correctly understood by many, including Jesus Himself, as Messianic, as conformed by Matt 27:43, 46, Mark 15:34.  Many Jewish interpreters  also understood this Psalm as messianic.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. You have inadvertently touched on the reason for my question: I am reading The Lost World of the Flood. The authors make the case that although the language surrounding the flood is plainly universal as written (undoing of creation), it is hyperbolic for theological purposes. They argue that Zeph 1 is textual evidence in support of the use of hyperbole, insisting that the language here is not a dual prophesy, but universal language being directed at Judah specifically. I did not see their assertion, but was unsure if my reading is reasonable

Comment: do you think I should open another, more specific question regarding the hermeneutics employed by the authors of The Lost World of the Flood, or update this one to be more specific? What I'm really interested in, is whether the author's references to other supposedly hyperbolic language in the OT really is valid hermeneutics and supportive of their assertion that The Flood would have been intended and understood hyperbolically by the author and their audience.

Comment: @cma0014 - hyperbolic language is when something is exaggerated about a particular object or person.  The language of Zeph 1 is not hyperbolic but universal - there is an important difference.

Comment: @cma0014 - look carefully at Gen 1 - it is a universal creation account BUT it is also a salvation story - God takes a useless, worthless and formless world and transforms it to a p[lace that is "very good".

Comment: The argument put forth by Walton and Longman is that the universal language itself is hyperbolic (I edited the question to quote the book). They also refer to how in Joshua 1-12, universal and all encompassing language is used to imply that ALL the land has been conquered, but then in Joshua 13 and Judges it is clear that is not the case. I was highly skeptical of their claim about Zephaniah, but not sure enough of my own knowledge to know if it was misplaced. It seems my skepticism could be well placed.

Comment: to elaborate further about their argument, they claim that the language here in the opening of Zephaniah 1 *is in fact* an exaggeration about the level of destruction the Babylonians will inflict upon Jerusalem. Clearly not everything was destroyed or wiped out *in Jerusalem*. They insist that this opening was directed exclusively at Jerusalem's coming destruction by Babylon

Comment: @cma0014 - Walton's commentaries are very well researched and useful.  However, I suggest that IMHO, some of his conclusions are over-reached.  That is, not all agree with his conclusions.

Comment: @cma0014 - Jerusalem was completely wiped out in the sense that the city became uninhabited and administratively dysfunctional

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142829/discussion-between-cma0014-and-dottard).